# can not find ipy_user_conf.py for Enthought python

Tags: shell, configuration, enthought

I have EPD. I would like to use the ipython shell. I think it's called 'pylab' in your distribution. I would like to be able to append to the system path ($pythonpath) at the moment when the shell loads. Unfortunately, I can not seem to locate the ipy_user_conf.py file that many users on the internet report is where I need to include a line to do that. Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're running IPython >= 0.11. (Note the IPython version is displayed when starting up the IPython shell.)

Older versions of IPython (pre-0.11) used `ipy_user_conf.py`, but IPython's configuration system was overhauled in 0.11. For details, see [this overview](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html). If you want to run some code on start up, you can add a python file in your IPython startup directory, which should be here:

`~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`

Any python code in that directory gets run on startup, so you can just create a new `.py` to modify your python path. If the startup directory doesn't exist, you may need to run:

`ipython profile create`

which creates those directories (plus some other goodies).